# Jmeter parametirisation of SAML Request, Response and Relay State

Tags: jmeter, saml

In JMeter HTTP Samplers I have to parameterize the HTTP Sampler containing parameters for SAML Request, SAML Response and Relay State but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your credentials you need to send the aforementioned parameters. The parameters can be found in responses for the previous requests.

You need to extract them from the previous responses using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

While sending the next request you need to add the variables from the previous step.

The process is known as [**correlation**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) and there is a lot of information regarding it in the Internet, i.e. [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites-with-jm)